# How do I get updates to cascade between to related DataRow objects on update?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I've been struggling long and hard with trying to get my SqlDataAdapters to work together to INSERT a row into both a Parent and Child table over a single SQL Transaction.
I can't seem to get the ID from the parent to cascade to the child table.

I am using MSSQL 2012. I've set up a Foreign Key Constraint between dbo.parent ID and dbo.child parent_id columns.
The result from the code below is:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Child_Parent". The conflict occurred in database "Test_Project", table "dbo.Parent", column'id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I was hoping somebody could help me fill in the missing gaps in order to get the code working.
Many thanks! :)

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(Local);Initial Catalog=Test_Project;Integrated Security=True;");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();


// Fetch Data from both tables
SqlDataAdapter parentAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Parent", sqlConn);
parentAdapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Parent");
parentAdapter.Fill(ds, "Parent");

SqlDataAdapter childAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Child", sqlConn);
childAdapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Child");
childAdapter.Fill(ds, "Child");


// Not sure if this step is necessary but I included it for good measure.
ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("ParentChildRelation", ds.Tables["Parent"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["Child"].Columns["parent_id"], true));


// Now add some data...
DataRow parentDr = ds.Tables["Parent"].NewRow();
parentDr["name"] = "Parent1";
ds.Tables["Parent"].Rows.Add(parentDr);

DataRow childDr = ds.Tables["Child"].NewRow();
childDr["parent_id"] = parentDr["id"]; // <- This column always fills NULL.
childDr["name"] = "Child1";
childDr.SetParentRow(parentDr, ds.Relations["ParentChildRelation"]);
ds.Tables["Child"].Rows.Add(childDr);


// Call DataSet updates back to SQL
SqlCommandBuilder parentCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(parentAdapter);
SqlCommandBuilder childCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(childAdapter);

if (ds.HasChanges())
{
    ds = ds.GetChanges();

    sqlConn.Open();
    SqlTransaction sqlTrans = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        parentAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;
        parentCmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand().Transaction = sqlTrans;
        parentAdapter.Update(ds, "Parent");

        childAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;
        childCmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand().Transaction = sqlTrans;
        childAdapter.Update(ds, "Child");


        sqlTrans.Commit();
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sqlTrans.Rollback();
        sqlConn.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've probably added an extra layer of complexity to this question. By taking out all code related to SqlTransaction I still get the same  "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" error.

Comment: its not a problem with the code so i dont think what you show us helps at all its about Table structure, i think an easy way is to create a view of the parent/child table and then update/insert into the view which will handle the inserts in both tables.

Comment: @drakoumelitos, while you can have multiple tables in a view, you can only modify one table in a view at a time.

Comment: in mssql? i could be getting this confused with an update will check

Comment: For sake of demonstration I created a new Database with only 2 tables (dbo.Parent and dbo.Child). They each have an autoincrementing 'id' PK column. A relationship is set between them (dbo.Parent.id is Primary Key column and dbo.Child.parent_id is the Foreign Key column). What else could be wrong with the SQL table structure?

Comment: Here is my DB Design http://i.imgur.com/x1BQxsB.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add this line:

```
ds.Tables["Child"].Constraints.Add(
    new ForeignKeyConstraint(
        ds.Tables["Parent"].Columns["id"],
        ds.Tables["Child"].Columns["parent_id"]
    )
);
```

See, though you have these constraints setup at the database level, you need to build this constraint so that the `id` field is **cascaded** down to the `parent_id` field after it gets back from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I removed that top line. I added in that codeblock (and also removed the DataRelation line in my original code) but now I get an exception on "ds.Tables["Child"].Rows.Add(childDr);" with this message "Column 'parent_id' does not allow nulls."

Comment: @Robula, ah that would be correct. Put that line back and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I still get "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Child_Parent". The conflict occurred in database "Test_Project", table "dbo.Parent", column'id'.
The statement has been terminated." when the code trys to execute this line: "childAdapter.Update(ds, "Child");" I've double checked to see that both the columns are set to int on the DB.

Comment: @Robula, where did you place the new code block that adds the constraint?

Comment: It's now in place where I put the "ds.Relations.Add" in my original code in place of that line.